The Lie exponential map coincides with the exponential operator defined by power series when the operator is bounded?
Following the thread The Lie exponential map coincides with the matrix exponential?:
Let $\mathcal{G}$ a Lie algebra of operators, $G$ its Lie group, and, $\exp\colon \mathcal{G}\to G$ the exponential map.
Let $A\in \mathcal{G}$ and suppose that $A\colon X\to X$ is an bounded operator on a normed space $(X,\left\|\cdot\right\|_X)$.
Question. Is $\exp(A)=\mathrm{e}^{A}:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!}$ holds? or this has not sense?
